# ¿Por que cuando hago un deploy desde VS me genera un archivo .Debug .Release?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un proyecto en visual studio el cual tengo un archivo de tipo `config` ejemplo `mifile` pero al publicarlo desde la plataforma (vs) me genera dos archivos mas aparte del original, los cuales son `mifile.Debug` y `mifile.Release` quedan con un total de 3 archivos. Pero mi archivo de configuracion general no sucede esto. ¿Por que? ¿A que se debe? ¿Esta bien que se generen? ¿Existen problemas si los elimino? Cabe destacar que tanto el .release como el .debug vienen sin info.

Comment: donde te genera esos archivos?

Comment: En la raiz de mi proyecto cuando lo publico en mi servidor de desarrollo o en mi maquina local.